# How to fix 'Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:' error in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to fetch results from a table using PL/SQL procedure

this is the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getEmpById(
       e_id IN employee.empid%TYPE,
       emp_name OUT employee.empname%TYPE,
       emp_desig OUT  employee.designation%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT empname,designation INTO emp_name, emp_desig FROM employee WHERE empid = e_id;
END;
/
```

and this is the calling block

```
DECLARE
   e_id:=&e_id;
   emp_name employee.empname%TYPE;
   emp_desig employee.designation%TYPE;
BEGIN
   getEmpById(e_id,emp_name,emp_desig);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name :  ' || emp_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Designation :  ' || emp_desig);   
END;
/
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
Enter value for e_id: 'AIT005'
old   2:    e_id:=&e_id;
new   2:    e_id:='AIT005';
   e_id:='AIT005';
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table LONG_ double ref
char time timestamp interval date binary national character
nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
```

Comment: Can you spot the difference between your declaration of `e_id` and your declarations of `emp_name` and `emp_desig`?

Comment: @apc the e_id is the variable name in the procedure but empid is the column name in the table that's the difference

Comment: that shouldn't cause any problems... but although I checked with the same name then also the same error is occurring

Comment: What I meant was, the declarations of `emp_name` and `emp_desig` included the datatype and your declaration of `e_id` did not. I was encouraging you to re-read your code and spot the error yourself but it seems you needed @littlefoot to point it out. One of the vital skills you must acquire to be a good programmer is the ability to read your own code with a cool eye. You simply can't post everything you write to this site and hope some kind stranger will debug it for you.

Comment: So, for future reference, whenever Oracle hurls `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ... when expecting one of the following:` it means your code contains a syntax error. So, look at the code in the line indicated - `ERROR at line 2:` - and see what is wrong. Sometimes the syntax error will be on a preceding line or a following line, but it will always be anchored to the line Oracle gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing E_ID's datatype (in the `DECLARE` section).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table employee (empid number, empname varchar2(10), designation varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into employee values (1, 'Little', 'Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace procedure getempbyid(
  2         e_id in employee.empid%type,
  3         emp_name out employee.empname%type,
  4         emp_desig out  employee.designation%type)
  5  is
  6  begin
  7    select empname,designation into emp_name, emp_desig from employee where empid = e_id;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set ver off
SQL> declare
  2     e_id employee.empid%type := &e_id;     --> you're missing E_ID datatype here
  3     emp_name employee.empname%type;
  4     emp_desig employee.designation%type;
  5  begin
  6     getempbyid(e_id,emp_name,emp_desig);
  7     dbms_output.put_line('Name :  ' || emp_name);
  8     dbms_output.put_line('Designation :  ' || emp_desig);
  9  end;
 10  /
Enter value for e_id: 1
Name :  Little
Designation :  Foot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```